# Push button to play mp4 video

Tags: audio, video, composite-video

I would like to know if anyone can help me with this, I would like to activate the reproduction of the video by pushing a button. The video will be played using Raspberry Pi.
Do I need to program the Raspberry Pi? How do I connect the button to the Raspberry Pi? At the moment I have been using Bright sign.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: It is disappointing that google offers no answers.  What search terms were you using?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called a *keyboard shortcut* or a *hotkey*. Assuming Raspbian, those are configured via the file `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`. The documentation on this file is available [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings). A quick example:

```xml
<keybind key="F1">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>mplayer -fs /path/to/file.avi</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```